# I'm Trying to apply the formulas for entire column for Google Translation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","",GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2:A,"en","ta")))
```

this is the formula I'm trying to translate but I'm not able to do it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpwZs.png)

The output I'm getting only one cell data

please refer the image

Comment: `GOOGLETRANSLATE` is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A100; LAMBDA(x; GOOGLETRANSLATE(x; "en"; "ta"))))
```

[image]